# How to use admin form on front-end in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, adminform

I want to use the admin form to create new products on the front end. How can it be possible?

[image: admin form]

Answer (score 1):

No this isn't possible, admin form are built upon ui components, their full structure is only available for admin.

Now that being said, it's always possible to adapt your design to make them look the same I guess. But this will be full custom and no native functionnality.